# Creating flicker animation with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create on mouse over flicker animation for an image. I want the animation will be invoked only one when the first time it got mouse over. To invoke another flicker animation, user must pull the cursor out of the image first, then hover it again. But it's still invoked even if I haven't pull the cursor of of the image and re-hover it yet (running the cursor around inside the image, and animation invoke multiple time).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.left > .img > img").mouseenter(function () {
        $("div.left > .flick").show();
        $("div.left > .flick").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

[Please take a look at my code here](http://jsfiddle.net/trongcuong1710/QPMT5/)

P/S: sorry for my bad English and poor explaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reasonably common problem, often overlooked.

When your overlay is displayed, it removes focus from the image underneath momentarily. When it fades back out, focus is put back on the image when the mouse is moved, meaning the animation happens more than once. The problem is caused by this loss of focus.

http://jsfiddle.net/QPMT5/1/

All you need to do is change your selector to the container, meaning that focus is only lost when the mouse leaves the *container*, *not* the image element within:

```
$("div.left").mouseenter(function () {
    $("div.left > .flick").show();
    $("div.left > .flick").fadeOut();
});
```

I've changed `div.left > .img > img` to `div.left`. A slightly cleaner version of this behaviour is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JFCqy/).

Comment: @muneeb That's because the OP's demonstration uses a `<div>` which is `display: block` by default. You should've been able to work this out

Comment: @muneebShabbir you're failing to realize the the technique is working perfectly but `.left` spans whole horizontal space which makes it look like it's not working. Try adding `.left{background:red}` to CSS and you'll see what the _problem_ is

Comment: Bojangles: Nice advice and explaining. Thanks you very much.
muneebShabbir: Thank you for your attention.
@Ejay: Thank for point out the dead zone, your comment really save me lot of time